# Average Precision i -1

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am new to this. I tried to train an SSD mobilenetv2 model using tensorflow object detection API. I followed this colab notebook
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wTMIrJhYsQdq_u7ROOkf0Lu_fsX5Mu8a#scrollTo=CjDHjhKQofT5
but during evaluation my average precision remains -1 at
num steps=25000.
What should I try next?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.